# How can I create multiple customer using one single request of rest api or graphQl in shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a very big amount of data and I have to update that on Shopify but Shopify allows only one creation at one request.

Are there any possibility for batch creation?

Answer (score 0):

No. Shopify API does not provide any bulk operations or batch processing.
But that does not mean that you have to update them one after the other. You can read the details about getting the most out of Shopify API at their blog.

[7 Tips to Maximize Your Use of The Shopify API](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/84051654-7-tips-to-maximize-your-use-of-the-shopify-api)

This explains you the concurrent scheduling of API requests. You have not mentioned any particular language that you are using, but the [Official Shopify module for NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node) is pretty robust and also takes care of rate limiting.